# How can I determine the current reliability [correctness] of the system time?

Tags: ntp, ntpd, chrony

I'm working on a project which will acquire a lot of timestamped data at fairly high resolution (50 samples per second) over a very long period of time (years).

The solution includes various failover mechanisms.  During the lifespan of this project it's reasonable to assume that some data-loggers will need to be replaced.  IE some will come online once data acquisition has already stated by others.

Given the nature of the data, it would be very bad if some data were recorded with inaccurate timestamps, even a handful of seconds out.  NTP should be solid enough for this solution, and even if network is lost for a few hours the drift on the internal clock should be too small to cause a significant problem. *Actually we care less about data during internet outages for esoteric reasons*.

**What bothers me** is what happens when a data-logger is rebooted. Or booted for the first time.  I want the device to reliably stabilise its system time using NTP before it meshes into the failover solution.

How can I determine the current reliability of the system time with respect to either chrony or ntpd.  That is, how can I get a value from either, telling me:

- how recently they last synchronised
- If possible, a confidence value in the last update*

By Confidence I mean something along the lines of total round trip time of the NTP packets... which is of course part of the NTP specification.

Comment: I don't have the spec to hand but ntpq will show you when it's synchronised, also how far away from "correct" time it is. I'm away for the weekend but can look if no-one else gets there first

Comment: @roaima Oh that's interesting. Full answer definitely welcome. What's nice about ntpq, reading the manual, is that it can work remotely.  That might even embed into an element of our failover logic.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether you read about the features of NTPv3, or the meaning of `chronyd`'s `tracking` output:

```text
chronyc> tracking
Reference ID    : AC14100E (p22.ntp-pool.domain.org)
Stratum         : 3
Ref time (UTC)  : Thu Nov 23 14:10:49 2023
System time     : 0.000021786 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000005573 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000017535 seconds
Frequency       : 13.186 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +0.002 ppm
Skew            : 0.018 ppm
Root delay      : 0.000255787 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.001269149 seconds
Update interval : 64.2 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```

Or `ntpq`'s `rl` output:

```text
associd=0 status=0618 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, no_sys_peer,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p17@1.4004-o Wed Jun 14 05:48:57 UTC 2023 (1)",
processor="x86_64", system="Linux/4.12.14-122.179-default", leap=00,
stratum=2, precision=-24, rootdelay=0.157, rootdisp=5.951,
refid=172.20.2.25,
reftime=e909db6b.de677ef7  Thu, Nov 23 2023 15:08:43.868,
clock=e909dc91.e033d3a0  Thu, Nov 23 2023 15:13:37.875, peer=12886, tc=9,
mintc=3, offset=+0.007816, frequency=+11.587, sys_jitter=0.222731,
clk_jitter=0.022, clk_wander=0.004
```

You could also try `sysinfo` and `kerninfo` in recent versions:

```text
ntpq> kerninfo
associd=0 status=0618 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, no_sys_peer,
pll offset:            0.005928
pll frequency:         11.5873
maximum error:         284.634
estimated error:       0.022
kernel status:         pll nano
pll time constant:     9
precision:             1e-06
frequency tolerance:   500
pps frequency:         0
pps stability:         0
pps jitter:            0
calibration interval   0
calibration cycles:    0
jitter exceeded:       0
stability exceeded:    0
calibration errors:    0
ntpq> sysinfo
associd=0 status=0618 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, no_sys_peer,
system peer:        172.20.2.25:123
system peer mode:   client
leap indicator:     00
stratum:            2
log2 precision:     -24
root delay:         0.135
root dispersion:    1.135
reference ID:       172.20.2.25
reference time:     e909dd93.de684491  Thu, Nov 23 2023 15:17:55.868
system jitter:      0.251147
clock jitter:       0.027
clock wander:       0.004
broadcast delay:    -50.000
symm. auth. delay:  0.018
```

you might want to read in the NTP FAQ on [Monitoring](https://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/ntp-s-trouble/#81-monitoring).